# Buffering an output file

Tags: perl, buffer, text-files, output

I have an output file that gets created in my perl script.  I'd like for all of the information to get outputted at once rather than gradually.  This would be done via buffering?  How would this work?

The relevant lines of code are:

```
 open( my $o,  '>', 'output.txt' ) or die "Can't open output.txt: $!";

 (then later on)
 print( $o ("$id"),"\n" );

 (then later on)
 close $o;
```

Comment: Note that turning on autoflusing doesn't cause the write to be atomic. It will be sent to the OS as one block, but the OS might write it in smaller blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to turn buffering *off* in order to make sure everything is printed at once. The old-fashioned way involved messing around with the special [`$|`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) variable directly, but a better way is to use [IO::File](https://metacpan.org/module/GBARR/IO-1.25/lib/IO/File.pm), which hides the details.

```
use IO::File;

open my $o, '>', 'output.txt' or die "Can't open output.txt: $!";
$o->autoflush( 1 );
$o->print( $id );
```

Comment: Oh, I took "at once" to mean "all together at the end", rather than "immediately"... OP, if I've misunderstood, this is the right answer :-)

Comment: The IO::File way (IO::Handle, actually) also messes with (`select` and) `$|`; it just hides the mess.

Comment: @ikegami, hiding the mess is the point. Sufficiently encapsulated horror is indistinguishable from a good API. :)

Comment: Oh I agree. You just made it sound like `$|` wasn't involved.

Answer (score 2):

Perl actually buffers its output by default -- you can switch this off by setting the special variable `$|`.

If you really want all your output at once, the safest bet is to just not send it for output until you're ready, e.g.:

```
use IO::Handle qw( );  # Not necessary in newer versions of Perl.

my @output;

(then later on)
push @output, $id;

(then later on)
open( my $o,  '>', 'output.txt' ) or die "Can't open output.txt: $!";
$o->autoflush(1); # Disable buffering now since we really do want the output.
                  #   This is optional since we immediately call close.
print( $o map "$_\n", @output );
close $o;
```

Comment: I thought your approach is interesting.  The other answer makes sense.  What I want to happen is that this is embedded in a longer script.  There is a while loop that is feeding in one line of input at a time.  That line of input then creates a line of output.  I do not want anything to happen with the $o file until after the entire while loop is completed ... that is, at the very end of the program.  So all at once, at the very end, I'd magically like this .txt to be created

Comment: Ah, good-oh -- that's certainly the intended effect of my version :-) It's very low tech -- using an array as an arbitrarily large buffer -- and there's no doubt a CPAN module that does it better, but it ought to do what you're describing.

Comment: Hey @ikegami, thanks for turning my bug-ridden half-solution into something more sane :-)